Should I finish a proof assuming a (possibly not independent) additional axiom?
I am writing a proof and I do not know how to proceed.
In the paper I’m writing, I have assumed four Axioms that I suspect imply one very particular thing. However, the proof contains a step that I can only do with the addition of a fifth axiom. After playing with many examples, it seems to me that my other axioms imply this fifth axiom, but (so far) I can’t show it.
So, the crossroad I’m facing is one in which:

I continue to work on showing that my other axioms imply the fifth;
I finish the proof assuming the fifth axiom (even though this fifth axiom may not be independent from the other four).

What would you do?

Explicitly State & Assume the fifth axiom , then finish the Paper/Article , where you might want to mention that you suspect that the 5 axiom might be redundant.
Send for review. When reviewers give some inputs , consider that.
Publish it : Maybe when some readers [ or you yourself ] figure out a way to show that 4 axioms imply the fifth axioms , then that itself would make the topic for a new Paper/Article on that Particular Issue where you can collaboratively refer to your Paper/Article !
ADDENDUM :
This Suggestion has Precedence : Euclid did that !
